# 1/109 and Fibonacci

Tags: recreational-mathematics, fractions, fibonacci-numbers

I saw the image at the end of this post and wanted to check it.
With the Mathematica code

```
Abs[N[1/109, 106] - Total[Table[Fibonacci[n] 1/10^(109 - n), {n, 1, 89}]]]
```

I get the following, with a lot of matching except at the start.

```
0.009798037939832989000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

That's pretty good, but that doesn't exactly match the claimed result.  is it possible to make this work exactly by using more than 89 Fibonacci terms?

[image]

Comment: Seems like it might be related to $$\frac{1}{109}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{110}}$$ and $$\frac{1}{110}=\frac{1}{10}-\frac1{11}$$

Comment: I don’t understand what’s being implied by the image. How many zeros and how many terms? Neither can be infinite, it seems.

Comment: I didn't know what was implied either, so I wanted to investigate. Seems to match... up to 89 terms.

Comment: Using python, I'm not getting any sum of the form $$\sum F_k10^k$$ that starts with the digits $917.$

Comment: Oh, I see. But $$f(0.1)=\frac{100}{100-10+1}=\frac{100}{91},$$ not $\frac{100}{109}.$ @Troposphere You'd need $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x-x^2}.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ah, right -- I had some signs wrong. It should actually be $\frac{1}{1+x-x^2}$.

Comment: For this to be true, there must be some $m,n$ such that $$109\sum_{k=0}^n F_k10^k=10^m-1,$$ and I'm just not seeing that. It ends in $n$ $9$ digits, but not all $9$s.

Comment: The full digits of $\frac{1}{109}$ before they repeat are: $$0.009174311926605504587155963302752293\\57798165137614678899082568807339449541\\2844036697247706422018348623853211\dots$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think the sum in the question has been fudged to ignore carries past the decimal point.

Comment: Yeah, not sure how they are fudging, but they are fudging. There's a reason the rightmost digits are Fibonacci, but I don't think there is a way to make the finite sum equal to $\frac{1}{109},$ and there is no sense to an infinite sum. @Troposphere

Comment: I.e., if we take 108 terms of the sum rather than 89 -- that is, all the terms that have any of their digits to the right of the decimal point -- then the _fractional part_ of the sum should match $1/109$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{F_n\times10^n}=\dots321100917\dots321100917\dots32110$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence
$$ F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} $$
Since this is a linear recurrence, we can run it in reverse and define *earlier* Fibonacci numbers as as function of later ones:
$$ F_{n} = -F_{n+1} + F_{n+2} $$
This lets us continue the sequence to negative indices:
$$ (F_{n})_{n\in \mathbb Z} = \ldots -8,5,-3,2,-1,1,0,1,1,2,3,5,8\ldots $$
If we flip this around with $G_{n}=F_{-n}$ we get a sequence satisfying
$$ G_0 = 0 \qquad G_1 = 1 \qquad G_n = -G_{n-1} + G_{n-2} $$

The [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for the $G_i$s is
$$ f_G(x) = G_0 + G_1x + G_2 x^2 + \cdots + G_n x^n + \cdots = \frac{x}{1+x-x^2} $$
In particular we have
$$ G_0 + \frac{G_1}{10} + \frac{G_2}{100} + \cdots + \frac{G_n}{10^n} + \cdots = \frac{0.1}{1.09} = \frac{10}{109} $$
Now things start to look like they may have something to do with the question!

Now long division by 109 turns out to repeat after 108 digits, after each remainder has been used exactly once.

Because the recurrence is *linear* we can use combinations of it to produce reverse Fibonacci sequences that start at other points -- in particular if we set
$$ H_n = F_{108-n} $$
such that the $H_i$ start with the first 108 Fibonacci numbers *backwards*, we get
$$ H_n = aG_n + bG_{n+1} $$
for some integers $a$ and $b$ which I could compute -- but I'd probably commit several off-by-one errors along the way, and it turns out the precise values don't matter.

In particular
$$ H_0 + \frac{H_1}{10} + \cdots + \frac{H_n}{10^n} + \cdots = \frac{10(a+10b)}{109} $$
still for some integer $a$ and $b$. What we learn from this is that the long division by $109$ *can* produce a digit sequence ending at $\ldots 8532110$ -- but since $\frac{1}{109}$ uses all the remainders, *it* must eventually produce the reverse Fibonacci pattern. All we need to do is find out *where* and adjust the numerator such that we start as just the right place -- but, by direct inspection of the division it turns out that $1$ *is* the right numerator -- **as long as we're okay by discarding any digits to the left of the decimal point**, which we'll certainly need to do in order to match the figure in the question.

Comment: There's probably a more enlightening reason why $1$ is the right numerator -- it also works with a denominator of $10099$ (one Fibonacci number per 2 digits) or $1000999$ (one Fibonacci number per 3 digits) -- but I can't offhand come up with a good argument for it.